# dispatch_async UITableView ReloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, dispatch-async

I have a problem, when start the viewDidLoad method, the data is loaded and displayed correctly in UITableView but when I have to reload the data by clickPopular method, the TableView is not updated.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

**viewDidLoad Method**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
slug = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Immagine = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
visite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
categorie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"recent" forKey:@"settings_home_filter"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self LoadJson];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [tableView reloadData];
            [self StopCaricamento];
        });
    });
}
```

**Popular Method**

```
-(IBAction)clickPopular:(id)sender{
    [tableView reloadData];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"popular" forKey:@"settings_home_filter"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self StartCaricamento];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self LoadJson];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [tableView reloadData];
            [self StopCaricamento];
        });
    });
}
```

**LoadJson Method**

```
-(void)LoadJson
{

    NSString *filtro = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"settings_home_filter"];

    NSString *stringachiamata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.mywebsite.com/videos/latest?count=100&ln=en&result_type=%@", filtro];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringachiamata]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    if(err != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Parsing JSON: %@", err);
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
        array = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"videos"];

        NSLog(@"%d", [array count]);

        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
        {            
            [Name addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [slug addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"slug_video"]];
            [Immagine addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"thumbnail_video_original"]];
            [visite addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"views_video"]];
            [categorie addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"category_name_video"]];
        }

    }
}
```

**StartCaricamento and Stop Caricamento Methods**

```
-(void)StartCaricamento{
    activityImageView.hidden = NO;
    [activityImageView startAnimating];
}

-(void)StopCaricamento{
    [activityImageView stopAnimating];
    activityImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: You don't call `StartCaricamento` in `viewDidLoad`. And you'd better not init `NSMutableArray` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: StartCaricamento is a void method that initiates a activityImageView. Where should I put init NSMutableArray?

Comment: @simalone whats wrong with init'ing `NSMutableArray` in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Putting data init method in viewController init will be better. Because before iOS6, if memoryWarning coming, the viewDidLoad will be called when the view appear again, and you may get a blank interface.

Answer (score 3):

you never clear the array when reloading...

meaning old entries remain upon reloading BEFORE you dispatch_async

```
[Name removeAllObjects];
[slug removeAllObjects];
[Immagine removeAllObjects];
[visit eremoveAllObjects];
[categorie removeAllObjects];
```

**actually.. do it as FIRST line of -(IBAction)clickPopular:(id)sender{**

Comment: [myArray removeAllObjects];    Add new ones, then reload data

Comment: also reconsider your naming. .. vars are written starting with a small letter and I would use plurals for array names

Comment: I tried but it returns an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
***`

Comment: sorry dont get what you're doing. this is the issue though. some code you're not showing us is likely trying to read the olddata somehow

Comment: These data access should also be done in the main thread (inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`). Otherwise when the background queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT) is clearing and adding new objects to these arrays the UITableView will crash if it tries to use old data it holds.